# Subversion (SVN) plugin for Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, subversion

I am in search for an alternative SVN client plugin for Visual Studio 2017.

I am using AnkhSVN since many years [AnkhSVN](https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) but it seems to be lesser supported years after years (max 1 release per year, no support for SVN 1.10 features, etc).

I know [VisualSVN](https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) but I find it less convenient to use than AnkhSVN and it's not free (even if a Community version exists).

I was also wondering myself if some Git plugins may also be usable with SVN repositories.

Comment: I don't want to answer this directly, as this may not fit directly as vsTortoise might work well (https://www.openhub.net/p/vstortoise). It's effectively a crossbreed between TortoiseSVN (the SVN explorer extension) and the VS plugin structure which is OK if you know that system well.

Comment: I am using TortoiseSVN everyday, but I was not aware of "vsTortoise". I'll have a look on it, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

TSVN is a new open source project. It's an extension in Visual Studio that acts as a UI for Tortoise. Same thing VisualSVN does except its free! https://github.com/sboulema/TSVN

Comment: I've been using TSVN since I found out that Ankh doesn't work with VS2019. It's not as convenient as a full integrated plug-in, but it does work!